# AngularJS, $destroy event don't propagate changes for double binded parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a simple directive with an isolated scope that is responsible to change a a value. When it is destroyed i want the value to be set to undefined. However the changes in the destroy function doesn't propagate changes.

Here is the code.
And again the problem is that outData is not set to 'undefined' outside this scope

```
scope: {
    outData: '=ngModel',
},
link: function (scope, elem, attars) {
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                scope.outData = undefined;
            })
}
```

I made a plunker to demonstrate the [problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/47o9iPlbibZZ2K61pxfu?p=preview).
Is this a bug? If not, is there a '$preDestroy' event to listen for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently angular brodcast the $destroy event from inside the $destroy function and before it returns it sets both $apply and $digest to noops. Meaning changes can not be noticed in the digest cycle (as far as my understanding goes).
I ended up creating a setter method by evaluating the actual object on the parent scope like so

```
 link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

   var dotPos = attrs.ngModel.lastIndexOf('.');
   var objString = attrs.ngModel.substr(0,dotPos);
   var paramString = attrs.ngModel.substr(dotPos+1,attrs.ngModel.length);
   var object = scope.$parent.$eval(objString);

   function setModel(val){
       object[paramString] = val
   }

   scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
       setModel(undefined);
   }
}
```

and then calling it in on the $destroy event.

!OBS! This only works when you use a object on your ng-model

`<tvx-select ng-model="anyObject.value" ... />`

It will not work for

`<tvx-select ng-model="value" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because you are changing the value/reference of the `outData` to be `undefined` and not anymore the outside value. You can use the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) in the directive without declaring a new scope in the directive.

In the directive of the Plunker example that you mention, you can remove the `scope` property and add `require: ngModel`. In this way you are able to inject the `ngModelController` in the `link` function and use methods to update the outside value:

```
 app.directive('tvxSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<select ng-model="intern">' +
        '<option value="nothing" selected>nothing<option>' +
        '<option value="forbidden">DONT SELECT<option>' +
        '</select>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attars, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.$watch('intern', function (newVal) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newVal);
              ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('I TOLD YOU NOT TO SELECT');
                ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me since I have more than just one in/out parameters. They could not all be ng-model.